# Difference between get_discount_total() and get_total_discount()?

Tags: php, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I notice in both **WC_Cart** and **WC_Order**, there's both ***get_total_discount()*** and ***get_discount_total()***.

What is the difference between these? Which should I use to get the *value* of the discount on a cart/order?

Answer (score 6):

Funny. I didn't notice it before.

`get_total_discount` will return a formatted value of the discount (with the currency symbol, wrapped with HTML).

`get_discount_total` will return just the value.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought from looking at the source - but I was getting confused - I've been staring at code for too long today.

Comment: This answer appears to pertain specifically to WC_Cart. The WC_Cart and WC_Order classes handle these methods differently, and it's recommended to [check the docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/) depending on your use-case.